# How do you make your beverage ice cold much quicker?

Tags: temperature, storage

When I put my beverage in the freezer, I have to wait at least an hour or more for it to get ice cold. Is there a hack to make your beverages ice cold within a much shorter time?

Comment: I can't answer, so i'll have to write in the comments...

You can wrap a wet paper towel around the bottle/can (it works best with cans) before you put it in the freezer.

This helps the heat being conducted out´of your drink and into the freezer, and can have your drink nice  and cold in 10-20 minutes in a -18C freezer

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you don't want ice in your beverage.

1. Keep ice in your freezer.
2. Place the container with your beverage into a larger container.
3. Pour ice in the gap.
4. Sprinkle salt on the ice.
5. While it is cooling, refill the ice trays.

Answer (score 0):

Ice water with an excess of ice.  The temperature is freezing and maximum contact.  You can mix (stir) the ice water for even faster cooling.

If the beer is warm can run it under a faucet for few seconds to save some of the ice.